# Access an item of the loop out of the loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

So i have a couple of item that iterate through from database using Jquery and for each of them I output a button to select that specific item and when I click on that row's button I want to POST the details to the controller in MVC.

```
$.each(data, function (i, val) {
    var item = $('<div></div>');
    item.append('<h2><a>' +val.Name+ '</a></h2>');              
    item.append('<a id="button">SELECT</a>');
    tab.append(item);
});
```

And I have this function for the button:

```
$('#myId').on('click', 'a#button', function () {
    alert('Name'+val.Name+'');  
    var item = { Name: val.Name };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: "{item:" + JSON.stringify(item) + "}",
        url: "/Person/GetData"
    });
});
```

If I add the function inside the loop it will iterate as many times as there are items in there. So how can I deal with this in order to send post the name after I press SELECT button?

Comment: why are you putting things in `<a>` tag??

Comment: Duplicate `id` attributes are invalid html. Use class names. And add the data to the element using `data-*` attributes, e.g.

Answer (score 1):

Use DOM traversal method to get the desired element to extract text to be passed to `$.ajax()`

As Identifiers in HTML must be unique use CSS class selector to target them

```
$.each(data, function (i, val) {
    var item = $('<div></div>');
    item.append('<h2><a>' + val.Name + '</a></h2>');
    item.append('<a class="button">SELECT</a>');
    tab.append(item);
});
```

In the event handler, use `.prev()` to target the sibling `<H2>` element

```
$('#myId').on('click', 'a.button', function () {
    var item = {
        Name: $(this).prev('h2').find('a').text()
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: {
            item: item
        },
        url: '@Url.Action("GetData", "Person")' //Note: this will not work in separate JS file
    });
});
```

Comment: Using `JSON.stringify()` and setting the `contentType` option is not really necessary since its a simple object.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I overlooked `contentType`, updated answer

Comment: I meant it should be deleted (so it use the default `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'` and then its just `data: item,`

Comment: Also for OP's benefit - better to use `url: '@Url.Action("GetData", "Person")',`

Answer (score 0):

Move the click to the bottom of the page outside any loop,

change the id to a class `item.append('<a class="button">SELECT</a>');` for your click event to select the proper value

```
$('#myId').on('click', 'a.button', function () {
    var val = $(this).prev('h2 a').text();//get the val.Name value
    var item = { Name: val};//create a object
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: item,//jquery will take care of the encoding
        url: "/Person/GetData"
    });
});
```